# Django-admin autoregister -- automatic model registration

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I want to register all application models into admin,is there any way to create automatically.
I have so many apps, I need to register automatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no short/direct way to do that, however you can write a short snipplet to achieve this. This is the snipplet I use to handle this. But, you must make some modifications to your admin files.

**somefile.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin


def admin_register(namespace):
    for name, model_admin in namespace.copy().iteritems():
        if name.endswith("Admin"):
            model = namespace[name[:-5]]
            try:admin.site.register(model, model_admin)
            except:raise
```

Then you must edit your *admin.py* files, and add `Admin` postfix to all of your admin clasess like:

**admin.py**

```
from somefile import admin_register

class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

and at the end of each *admin.py* file, add following

```
admin_register(namespace=globals())
```

this will take all defined classes, functions and variables in your global namespace and choose ones which ends with `Admin`. You need to include this line at the end of each admin file.

For Admin Class definitions, if you do not want to specify any attribute to Admin class, just write `pass` . Just add Admin classes for those you wish to see in your admin panel.